# rake db:migrate securely on staging and production environments

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, deployment, rake, production-environment

I enjoy using rake to manage my migrations in the development environment, where I have allowed my rails app full permissions on the dev DB.

However, in the staging and production environments, my application only has write access, not  the ability to alter tables.

I'd like to continue using `rake db:migrate` in staging and production, but the problem is that `rake db` uses the same user as my rails app, which doesn't have sufficient privileges.

Does anyone know an easy way around this problem, without having to allow administrative db privileges in my rails app.

Eg, if I could specify `-username` and `-password` when I run `rake db`, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify some `migration` connection in your `config/database.yml` with a user/pass for the properly-privileged user and run

```
RAILS_ENV=migration rake db:migrate
```

**Edit** It looks like something like this might work (though I've never tested it over a remote connection, only locally). Add the following to your `config/database.yml`.

```
<%
require 'highline/import'

def request_input(msg, show_input = true)
  ask(msg) { |q| q.echo = show_input }
end
%>

migration:
  # Other connection information here (host, adapter, etc..)
  username: <%= request_input "Username:" %> 
  password: <%= request_input "Password:", false %>
```

When you run

```
RAILS_ENV=migration rake db:migrate
```

You will be prompted to enter the username and password for the connection. Make sure to add

```
gem 'highline'
```

to your `Gemfile`.

Source: http://dzone.com/snippets/request-database

Comment: I did think of this, however, the problem is that the root level db authentication info is sitting in an unencrypted text file. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: The highline solution is working just fine in production. thanks! interestingly it asks for username and pwd twice, I'm not complaining though - this is a vast improvement on what we had previously :-)